# Как работает этот указатель на функцию?

Tags: указатели, c++, функции

```
void error(int i);
void (*p)(int);
p=&error;
(*p)(1);
```

Для начала попробую прочитать вот вторую строчку, то есть p - это указатель на функцию возвращающую значения типа void. Почему я прочитал так и в частности "типа void", потому что использовал методику [отсюда](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116255/). Но а по каким правилам это все происходит?
Я примерно понимаю это как :

1. реализация функции(просто для примера, а так объявление тоже было, но его тут не написал);
2. уже читал его выше, дополню только то, что группирующие скобки нужны для того, чтобы был указатель на функцию, а не имя функции и её возвращающий тип `void*`. Странно что после прочтения одной книги по C++, я не встретил там упоминания о основном типе и производном и по этому меня такая запись удивила, что уж говорить о такой `int (*(*foo)())();`, это было бы вообще темным лесом, если бы не та методика.
3. Тут указателю "p" присваивается адрес, но адрес на что, на прототип функции?
4. Указатель разыменовывается и просто на его место подставляется имя функции `error` и получается `(error)(1)`? То есть можно любую функцию оборачивать группирующими скобками и от этого суть не меняется.  
    Такая запись нужна только потому что этого требует указатели, то есть чтобы указатель имел тот же тип что и указываемый объект?

Comment: Авторы руководства по GO вдоволь поиздевались над сишными описаниями типов. И есть за что.

3. Подставляется адрес функции error. Если она описана в этой единице трансляции, то это может сделать транслятор, если нет, то ссылка внешняя, и адрес подставляет линковщик.

4. Скобки -- для устранения неоднозначности. (Неправильно выразился: требование синтаксиса. Иначе получается "взять значение по адресу p(1). Поскольку результат имеет тип void, то и значение по его адресу взять нельзя).

Лениво искать, но транслятор не ругается на `p=error;` и `p(1);`

Comment: 3. P присваивается адрес реализации. то есть, можно считать, что здесь храниться адрес в памяти, где расположен код функции. А то, что параметры соответствуют, проверяет компилятор.

Comment: В http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#chapter2 эти сокращения называются 'short form' для `p=error;` и 'C short way' для `p(1);`

Comment: БОЛЬШАЯ ПРОСЬБА!

Теги с++ и c++ не являются идентичными. В одном случае с - русская, во втором - английская. Прошу везде использовать правильный тег c++.

Comment: @mzarb, там (после ответа, где Вы написали много комментариев) у меня лимит комментариев кончился. Попробую ответить здесь.

IMHO в основном Вы понимаете правильно. Смотрите в gcc

    void *p = (void *)puts, (*fp)() = p;
    fp("call puts");   // это работает
    //  p("call puts");  а это не компилится

а в g++ надо

      void *p = (void *)puts, (*fp)(const char *) = (void (*)(const char *))p;


Т.е. для компилятора важны формальности. Особенно для С++. Это и в самом деле правильно (уменьшает количество глупых ошибок).

Так что, посмотрите внимательно на ответ @alexlz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Вообще тема описания указателей на функции пожалуй самая запутанная в Си и особенно в С++. Наибольшие проблемы возникают с корректным для компилятора описанием функции, возвращающей адрес функции.

Практически надо понимать, что указатель на функцию это адрес первой машинной команды тела функции и ее вызов производится путем загрузки этого адреса в регистр и выдачи инструкции call для регистра, например

```
movq    -16(%rbp), %rax   // загрузка адреса функции
call    *%rax             // вызов
```

На практике удобно (согласен, что не совсем правильно, но реально работает) описывать адреса функций как `void *` и при необходимости использовать приведение типа.

Например: (работает и в Си и в С++)

```
// fu1.c вызов функций по адресу
#include <stdio.h>

// если первый аргумент не 0, то 
// возвращает второй аргумент (передаваемую функцию),
// иначе определенную в fu2.c функцию
extern void *getfu(int, int (*f)(int));

// возвращает массив определенных в fu2.c функций
extern void **getvfu();

static int
qq (int i) // передаем эту функцию как аргумент в getfu()
{
  return printf("qq=%d\n",i);
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int i,
    (*p)(int);

  void **v = getvfu();  // получим массив функций из fu2.c
  for (i = 0; v[i]; i++)
    ((int (*)(int))(v[i]))(i);

  p = (int (*)(int))(av[1] ? getfu(0,0) : getfu(1,qq));
  int rc = p(10);
  return printf ("rc = %d\n",rc) < 0;
}

// fu2.c функции и их массив
#include <stdio.h>

static int
fu (int i) { 
  return printf ("fu=%d\n",i); 
}

void *
getfu (int fa, int (*f)(int))
{
  return (void *)(fa ? f : fu);
}

static int f1 (int i) { return printf ("f1: %d\n",i); }
static int f2 (int i) { return printf ("f1: %d\n",i); }
static int f3 (int i) { return printf ("f1: %d\n",i); }

void **
getvfu()
{
  static void *fv[] = {(void *)f1, (void *)f2, (void *)f3, (void *)fu, 0};

  return fv;
}
```

Транслируем и запускаем

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++  -c fu1.c fu2.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ fu[12].o -o a++
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a++ 1
f1: 0
f1: 1
f1: 2
fu=3
fu=10
rc = 6
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc fu1.c fu2.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 1
f1: 0
f1: 1
f1: 2
fu=3
fu=10
rc = 6
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
f1: 0
f1: 1
f1: 2
fu=3
qq=10
rc = 6
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Возможно это (не совсем корректное решение) окажется полезным.

Кстати, кто-нибудь может напишет действительно правильный (желательно собирающийся и работающий) вариант для С и С++.

Comment: Хм, мне казалось, что указатели на функцию [не приводимы](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12358843/276994) к указателям на `void`.

Comment: @VladD (1) не `void` а `void *`. (2) Против лома... (язык-то низкоуровневый).

@avp 

     На практике удобно (согласен, что не совсем правильно, но реально работает) описывать адреса функций как void * и при необходимости использовать приведение типа.

А за такие удобства -- пороть. И без жалости. И так язык программиста не шибко защищает, да ещё и имеющуюся защиту ломать...

Comment: @alexlz: у меня ж там "указатель на `void`"...

Comment: @alexlz: я тоже, как раз пью кофе :-)

Comment: ((int (*)(int))(v[i]))(i); как это читается?
И почему получается rc = 6 ?

Comment: @mzrab, 

    ((int (*)(int))(v[i]))(i);

это вызов функции из v[i]:

    (v[i])  взять адрес из i-го элемента v[] это тип void *

    (int (*)(int)) это приведение типа void *, т.е. указателя 
                   неизвестно какого типа к указателю (т.е. адресу)
                   на функцию, принимающей аргумент типа int
                   и возвращающей результат типа int

Таким образом получаем адрес (указатель) нужного вида (с т.з. компилятора)

    (...)(i); собственно вызов функции (из v[i]) c параметром i

По сути это приведение к указателю 

    int (*p)(int);


как в вопросе.

Comment: rc = 6  - это результат, возвращаемый `printf()` - количество печатаемых байт. 

см. man 3 printf.

Comment: @alexlz, 

    А за такие удобства -- пороть. И без жалости.

а правильно написать сможете?

Comment: @mzarb `((int (*)(int))(v[i]))(i)` Привести v[i] к типу (int (*) (int)), т.е. указатель на целочисленную функцию целого и вызвать эту функцию с параметром (i).

Comment: [@avp][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/232/avp
А почему вообще возможно писать в массиве указателей на функции, элементы не только вида `(void *) f1,` но и просто f1 и *f2 ? То есть `f1` и `*f1` будут неявно приведены к типу `void*`, а выглядеть это будет как `(void (*) (void))f1` и `(void (*) (void))*f2`? Это работает из-за совместимости с Си или в этих двух способах написания есть какой то смысл?

Comment: @alexlz, точно!!!

Переведите свой комментарий в ответ (только `int (**fv)(int) = getvfu();` д.б. в другом файле) и еще хорошо бы написать для всех правила, по которым создаются такие описания функций.

Мне кажется, я уловил суть. Само имя функции и ее аргументы описываются в "первых" скобках, тип возвращаемый функцией-результатом в начале, а ее аргументы во "вторых" скобках. 

Так?

--

@mzarb, не очень понял Ваш вопрос в комментарии. Он о коде в комментарии @alexlz? Там типы правильно описаны.

Если о моем ответе, то в Си можно выбросить (void \*), а в С++ нет (компилятор более строгий).

Comment: [@avp][1]
Нет, вопрос был к вам. Почему преобразование указателей в массиве проходит понятно, так как массив типа `void*`, а это значить что "Указатель типа void может быть преобразован к указателю любого другого типа только явным приведением типа. Но указатель любого типа может быть неявно преобразован к указателю типа void." И я спрашивал как именно выглядит это преобразование, просто `(void *)f1` или `(void (*) (void))f1`?  
...

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/232/avp

Comment: ...  
Так же почему возможна запись `f1`, потому что `f1` приведется к `(void*)` или потому что имя любой функции - это указатель и при написании его в массиве просто передается адрес этой функции? 
И ещё пару моментов не ясные. Все не помещается, по этому заранее извиняюсь за отрывки.
> Практически надо понимать, что указатель на функцию это адрес первой машинной команды тела функции  

Ясно видимо у меня были недопонимания с тем, что происходит в сигнатуре функции, то есть я думал что она тоже вызывается при вызове функции, точней что туда что-то передается, по этому для меня было  
...

Comment: ...  
непонятно зачем указывать код вида `(*p)(int)` и как потом параметр передастся в функцию. Вчера прочитал ещё ответ в этом [вопросе][2] и там узнал что переменные не передаются, а присваиваются в месте между телом функции и сигнатурой, а не в самой сигнатуре. 
Возможно это очевидно для многих, но после этого я смог 
...
[2]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/178009/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=180400#180400

Comment: ...  
по новому посмотреть на ваше сообщение и вот мои мысли по этому поводу(на примере кода в вопросе): указание полного типа объекта вида void `(*p1)(int)`, а не просто `void *p`, нужно потому что функция объявлена как `void error(int i)`; и после её вызова с помощью кода `(*p1)(2)` сначала будет инициализирована переменная `i` значением `2`, а потом начнется выполнение с первой команды тела функции, то есть сначала выполнится эта часть `(2)`, а потом запуск первой команды тела функции с помощью этой части `(*p)`. Поправьте или дополните пожалуйста, если я не правильно понял.  
...

Comment: @mzarb дополнил свой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) Правильно -- это так?

```
 static int f1 (int i) { return printf ("f1: %d\n",i); }
 static int f2 (int i) { return printf ("f1: %d\n",i); }
 static int f3 (int i) { return printf ("f1: %d\n",i); }
 static int fu (int i) { return printf ("fu=%d\n",i);  }
 int (** getvfu())(int) {
   static int (*fv[])(int) = {f1, f2, f3, fu, 0};
   return fv;
 }
 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     int (**fv)(int) = getvfu();
     fv[0](1);
     fv[1](2);
     fv[2](3);
     fv[3](4);
     return 0;
}
```

Случайно наткнулся ещё вот на что: [Reading C type declarations](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html)

[[@mzarb](/users/11390/mzarb)](/users/11390/mzarb)

```
там узнал что переменные не передаются, а присваиваются в месте между телом функции и сигнатурой,
```

Не совсем понятно, что Вы написали. Традиционно (допускаю, что не всегда и везде) параметры в функцию в C передаются через стек. Есть разные методы передачи параметров: "по значению" (передаётся значение, функция с ним может делать, что хочет, в вызывающей программе/функции значение параметра не меняется). В C все параметры именно так и передаются. Есть метод передачи "по ссылке" -- в функцию/подпрограмму передаётся ссылка на переменную (или значение, и там может получиться смешно, если функция будет это значение менять. Одна из типичных ошибок). В функции идёт работа с переменной-фактическим параметром через эту ссылку. Классика жанра -- фортран. В Си такого нет, но есть возможность смоделировать такую работу, передав в качестве параметра указатель на переменную. Сам указатель передаётся "по значению", а с переменной функция может делать всё, что захочет.

Есть другие методы, например в алгол-60 был метод передачи параметров "по имени". В большинстве случаев выполнял те же задачи, что и метод передачи параметров "по ссылке", но имел некоторые дополнительные возможности (сейчас в некоторых языках есть подобные вещи -- параметры-блоки кода, вроде Obj-c, perl и пр.). Реализация -- thunk'и.

Сигнатура тут ни причём. Она служит только для проверки правильности и добавки некоторых приведений типа по умолчанию.

Comment: @alexlz: в ту же кассу http://cdecl.org/

Comment: @alexlz, точно!!!

Думаю этот ответ будет полезен многим для правильного описания функций, возвращающих функции.

Я это правило могу сформулировать так:

описание самой функции, ее имя и параметры заключаем в скобки и вместо типа пишем звездочку (или несколько, в зависимости от уровня косвенности), тип результата возвращаемой функции пишем перед скобками, а ее аргументы описываем после скобок.

Соответственно, для прототипа  в начале пишем, например, `extern` и  завершаем такое описание `';'`, а если пишем саму функцию, то заканчиваем ее телом в `{ ... }`.